# подключение oracle database к приложению javaFX

Tags: java, база-данных, oracle, jdbc

установил Oracle Database 11g + SQLDeveloper. Создал нового пользователя и connection. При выполнении sqlplus / as sysdba получаю ошибку ORA-01031: insufficient privileges. если войти через /nologin, а потом в нового пользователя, получишь тут же ошибку, если залогиниться в system, STARTUP выдаёт ту же ошибку. Как это исправить и подключить базу к приложению в IntelliJIdea?

Comment: Вы пробовали войти с помощью браузера?

Comment: "Создал нового пользователя и connection" -  как создали, какого пользователя, какую connection?

Comment: по поводу того, где создавался юзер. юзер создавался в sqldeveloper`е, там вход через сис работает. права у нового пользователя нужные есть. там же от имени этого юзера создал коннекшн и таблицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос достаточно абстрактный, но попробую предположить, что Вашему пользователю, которого Вы создали, не хватает привилегий для подключения. 
Попробуйте создать пользователя следующей командой:

```
CREATE USER <<YOUR_USER>> IDENTIFIED BY <<YOUR_USER_PASSWORD>> DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP PROFILE DEFAULT ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, IMP_FULL_DATABASE, CREATE VIEW, UNLIMITED TABLESPACE, CREATE JOB TO <<YOUR_USER>>;
```

Следует заменить `<<YOUR_USER>>` на название своего пользователя.
Либо просто попробуйте выполнить вторую строку, которая грантает юзеру возможность коннекта.

Надеюсь это поможет.

Comment: А где выполнить эти команды?

Comment: в sqlplus. То есть подключаетесь пользователем sys к sqlplus (у вас выше команда подключения есть sqlplus / as sysdba). А там выполняете по очереди две команды, заканчивая каждую точкой с запятой. Вы, наверное, пользователя не через консоль создавали?

Comment: Как автор вопроса указал: "При выполнении sqlplus / as sysdba получаю ошибку ORA-01031: insufficient privileges". И как ему выполнить команды как в вашем ответе?

Comment: Да, действительно. Меня запутала строчка "Создал нового пользователя и connection". Я понял вопрос, что не получается подключиться к вновь созданному пользователю. Но тогда непонятно как создавался этот пользователь, если даже к сису подключиться не получается. 
Но возвращаясь к проблеме - тут, конечно, много причин уже может быть... как очевидная - некорреткно настроенный tnsora и так далее. Посмотрите - http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_11g_connect_sysdba_ora_01031.htm, а свой ответ через пару минут удалю, чтобы не путать народ.

Comment: Я уже дал комментарий под вопросом. Пока ТС не даст ответ, его вопрос непонятен и будет скорее всего закрыт. Ответ удалять не спешите, если ТС всё таки дополнит вопрос необходимой информацией, то Вы можете тогда поправить/видоизменить ответ.

Comment: @0xdb, дада)) я уже зарейтил ваш коммент